# How to access this in Kotlin sequence generator?

Tags: kotlin, iterable

I'm using sequence to produce a `Iterable<T>` as a member function in Kotlin, but in the sequence lambda `this` refers to `SequenceScope<T>`. I want to access `this`, how do I do this?

```
class A{
fun getSomething() = sequence {
yield(this)// this means Scope, I want to return this object
}
}
```

Comment: So are you trying to access the instance of `A`? If so then you need `this@A`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to reference the outer scope with: `this@A`. This is explained here: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/this-expressions.html#qualified-this